# Plotting multiple lines in matplotlib Python, dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph

Hello fellow programmers!

I have just started learning Python a month ago and started scraping the web for data but I have run into some difficulties creating a graph using matplotlib.

So, I have collected data for a sports league and would like to create a graph that shows each teams total points per season. The data are in a Pandas dataframe. There are around 40 different teams, and not all teams exist for every year.

However I'm having difficulties creating a graph that shows the total points per season for each individual team, all I have managed to do so far is create a graph for all teams combined points per season...

I have looked into subplots but have not managed to figure out how to proceed.

My code:

```
season_group = df.groupby("Season")

quantity_points = season_group.sum()["TP"]

seasons = [season for season, df in season_group]

plt.plot(seasons, quantity_points)
```

The graph I'm getting:
[image: How Data looks]

The shape of the dataframe:
[image: How Data looks]

How I want the graph to look
[image: How I want graph to look]

Comment: Please don't embed data as images. Post the text directly here on SO.

Comment: Thank you for your help I tried doing so but it didnt work =)

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"? If you want other people to help you, you better be specific about your problem. `print(df.head(10))` did not print anything? Maybe the columns were truncated which can be prevented by `pd.options.display.max_columns = None`. Maybe the columns were not all in one line, which can be prevented by `pd.options.display.expand_frame_repr = False`. Maybe you don't know how to post text on SO. How would we know? Don't let us guess.

Comment: Hello Mr T. 
Thank you for your answer. I added the graph I managed to produce in matplotlib in the post. I have been looking into subplots but have not managed to find a way how you break out the individual teams when producing the graph such as in the colored picture at the bottom of the post. Any ideas where I could find that information or do you know how one could proceed?

Comment: A) Pandas plots columns vs index. You can [reshape](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html#reshaping) your data so `Team` represent columns and index (or another column) is `season`. B) Pandas uses matplotlib for plotting, so you could use matplotlib by feeding your arrays into a line plot. [Their tutorials & examples](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/index.html) are very helpful. Still involves data reshaping. C) `seaborn` is built on top of matplotlib/pandas. Their lineplot takes a [third argument `hue`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html)

Comment: Thank you again Mr T. I managed to solve it using seaborn!

Comment: Good. But if you want to learn Python, I suggest spending some time with those pandas/matplotlib tutorials. Seaborn makes it comfortable to achieve certain plot types but for full functionality, you sometimes have to revert to matplotlib/pandas.

Comment: I definitely will look into them aswell!